# How to persist android LatLng object with ORMLite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I´m having some problems trying to persist the following class on Android with ORMLite:

```
@DatabaseField
private int id;
@DatabaseField
private String name;
@DatabaseField
private String address;
@DatabaseField
private LatLng location;
@DatabaseField
private float rating;
```

The problems is that location field is of LatLng which comes with google maps Android library so I don´t have access to it. When I try to persist this class with ORMLite I´m getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store
>   class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng for field location. Use
>   another class or a custom persister

Does anyone know how to solve this without changing the location type? I´ve tried to create a custom persister but it´s not clear to me how to do it correctly with the examples given by the documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create ORMlite entity  like LatLngEntity and store one and add to reference to your model entity. Second way is simply add two fields(lat and lon) separately in you model entity. I have used first way